# How can I get my promise to wait for user input instead of running immediately?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, es6-promise

I have an array made up of selections made by the user. Each selection is made up of a user id and a promise, which is supposed to run the filter function once a user inputs their selection. However, it doesn't wait for user selection and instead skips straight to the conditional check. Since no selections were made, the length is always < 1.
What am I missing to make sure it stops and waits for user input?

```
function filter (x) {
        if (x.author.id === client.user.id) {
          return false;
        };

        var content = x.content.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).filter(function (value, index, self) {
          return self.indexOf(value) === index;
        });

        if (content.length !== actions.pick) {
          x.channel.send("Invalid number of unique suggestions.");
          return false;
        };

        if (verifyContent(content)) {
          x.channel.send("**Selection confirmed.**");
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        };

        function verifyContent (a) {

          for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            var index = parseInt(a[i]);

            if (isNaN(index) || a[i] % 1 !== 0) {
              x.channel.send("Invalid.");
              return false;
            };

            if (game.getPlayer(x.author.id).cards[index - 1] === undefined) {
              x.channel.send("Card(s) selected contain an invalid range.");
              return false;
            };
          };

          return true;

        };

      };
      picks.push({id: game.players[i].id, promise: dmc.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 60*1000})});
    };
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < picks.length; i++) {
    var selection = await picks[i].promise[0]
    selection = selection !== undefined ? selection.content.split(',').map(x => x.trim()) : new Array();
    if (selection.length < 1) {
       channel.guild.members.cache.find(x => x.id === picks[i].id).user.send("I randomly picked 
       your response from your choice of white cards!");
  }
```

Comment: maybe you wrote wrong `await picks[i].promise[0]`. Change to `await picks[i].promise` without brackets.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ident, but "picks" is the array of user selections. Since it isn't waiting for user input, "picks" ends up being an empty array.

Comment: i'm not sure that having a promise wait on user input is a good idea and not violating some kind of design paradigm.  Why don't you just have your code run when an event fires?

Comment: @SergioCabral That helped it to stop and wait for user input, thank you! But now the promise is pending indefinitely, any other thoughts? lol